# Laravel 4 - Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4, duplicates

I am trying to create a user management system. Everything is going fine until the time I wanted to implement the "Edit User" part. I have successfully avoid the 'problem' with the unique username and e-mail fields, by ignoring the user's id in my rules.
The problem is, when I am trying to update a user to a non-existing username or email, everything is working. But when I am trying to do the same thing for something that already exists, I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'existing_username_here' for key 'users_username_unique'

I already have the 'unique' field implemented in my rules, so I don't know what's wrong with that. Is there a way so I can catch this specific exception and show it to the user? Is there a way to outreach this problem? I have been searching for hours and hours and I can't seem to find anything useful.

**Edit:** It seems like it tries to insert a new raw instead of updating the existing one...! I don't know why that happens. Any thoughts?

**AdminController.php**

```
public function update($id)
    {
        if ( ! $this->validator->isValidForAdminEdit()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors())->withInput();
    }

    $user = $this->register->getUserById($id);
    $data = [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
        'activated' => Input::get('activated'),
        'assign_role' => Input::get('assign_role')
    ];

    $updatedUser = $this->adminRegister->update($data); 

    return Redirect::to('admin/users')
    ->with(['flash_message' => "The user $updatedUser->username has been edited.",
            'flash_type' => 'success']);

}
```

**DbAdminRepository.php**

```
public function update(array $data)
    {

    $user = Register::find($data['id']);
    $user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
    $user->username = $data['username'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    if (isset($data['password']) && ($data['password'] != "")) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
    }
    $user->activated = (! isset($data['activated']) ? (int)0 : (int)1);
    $role = $data['assign_role'];

    $user->save();   // THE PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE
    $user->roles()->detach();
    $user->roles()->attach($role);

    return $user;
}
```

**Validator.php**

```
public function isValidForAdminEdit(array $rules = array())
    {
    // if there are no rules return true.
    if(!isset(static::$rules)) return true;

    $rules = self::processRules($rules ? $rules : static::$admin_edit_rules);
    $validator = V::make($this->attributes, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->errors = $validator->messages();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected function processRules(array $rules)
{
    // get the model's ID.
    // If the ID is null, it's a new Model, so let's strip out the id completely.
    $id = $this->attributes['id'];
    $replacement = $id == null ? "" : "," . $this->attributes['id'];
    array_walk($rules, function(&$item) use ($replacement)
    {
    // Replace placeholders
        $item = stripos($item, ',:id:') !== false ? str_ireplace(',:id:', $replacement, $item) : $item;
    });
    return $rules;
}

public function errors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}
```

**UserValidator.php**

```
static $admin_edit_rules = [
    'username' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:32|Unique:registers,username,:id:',

    'email'  => 'Required|Between:3,64|Email|Unique:registers,email,:id:',

    'first_name' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:80|Alpha',

    'password'  =>'AlphaNum|Between:4,20|Confirmed',

    'password_confirmation'=>'AlphaNum|Between:4,20',

];
```

Comment: Kalispera :) How are your routes working? Seems to me, you are posting to the route responsible for creating a record, not updating.

Comment: Hello there ;) . Here are my routes
Route::get('admin/users/create', array(
    'uses'    =>  'DashboardController@create',
    'as'      =>  'admin.create'
  ));

  Route::post('admin/users', array(
    'uses'    =>  'DashboardController@store',
    'as'      =>  'admin.createUser'
  ));

  Route::get('admin/users/{id}/edit', array(
    'uses'    =>  'DashboardController@edit',
    'as'      =>  'admin.editUser'
  ))->where('id', '\d+');

  Route::post('admin/users/{id}/edit', array(
    'uses'    =>  'DashboardController@update',
    'as'      =>  'admin.updateUser'
  ))->where('id', '\d+');